# Unable to send the cookie. Size of 'mage-messages' is 4190 bytes in reports

Tags: magento-2.3

I am getting this issue when I have heavy traffic on my site. I am using Magento 2.3.2.

> Unable to send the cookie. Size of 'mage-messages' is 4190 bytes in reports

Comment: see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8276, the issue should be fixed in your version but I still have it in 2.2.8.